# Adicionar dados pelo Codeigniter com Ajax

Tags: codeigniter

Sou novo com desenvolvimento MVC e até agora estou com dificuldade para identificar o erro quando tento salvar os registros do meu form.
Da a mensagem de erro: 403 (Forbidden). Estou utilizando o Codeigniter.

Minha função:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-save').click(function () {
        var dados = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/centros/cadastrar');?>",
            async: true,
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Reparas-te que tens `});` a mais no código? é mesmo assim ou foi só no copy/paste aqui que isso surgiu?

Comment: Onde dá esse erro? na consola? Se fazes `location.reload();` no sucesso do ajax porquê não fazer um POST simples sem AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Pouca informações passadas. Mesmo assim, vou tentar ajudar:

```js
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#botao").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dados   = $('#formulario').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('centros/cadastrar'); ?>",
                data: dados,
                success: function(response){ 
                    // TODO faca algo  
                }, 
                error: function(response){
                    // TODO
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Vale lembrar que o site_url('centros/cadastrar') deve ser o direcionamento para o controller que irá fazer a inserção.